# KMM - How to add Retrofit into :shared module (commonMain)

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I want to add Retrofit into :shared module (commonMain).

```
sourceSets["commonMain"].dependencies {
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")
}
```

But in `commonMain` I can't see Retrofit class. In `androidMain` I can see it. That is a magic. I don't add Retrofit into `androidMain`.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

Retrofit is a Java & Android library, this means you can share it only between JVM targets in KMP.

You can't use Retrofit in your shared code, if you're building a KMM app (iOS and Android targets) unless you create an abstraction over it, and provide the native/iOS implementation (which is a tedious amount of work).

You could use [Ktor](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/use-ktor-for-networking.html#connect-ktor) instead.